# Infinite Product Series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, infinite-product

I was solving my school book and got bored so I made my own question for solving myself and to entertain myself.

I made something like this: 
Find solution of 
$$ \log_{e}x= \sqrt{x\sqrt{x\sqrt{x\sqrt{x...\infty}}}} $$

What I did in solution was this(sorry I was not able to add the solution in coded form for better representation as I am using stack exchange from my Android):-

https://bit.ly/3cLFCgv

So, I got x=1 as my solution **BUT** if we put x=1 in the former statement it will not hold true as it will come as 0=1 which is actually not true!!

Please let me know where have I mistaken!!

Thank you in Advance!!

Comment: Please use [mathjax formatting](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your calculations

Comment: So, assuming you define the infinite radical properly, etc... why do you assume there *is* a solution? Your argument says "if there is a solution, then this solution is $x=1$." (You proceed by implications, not equivalences.)

Comment: You only sowed that **if** there is a solution **then** it equals $1$.

Comment: Didn't got it sir.... I think to find the solution of a given expression we have to first assume it true.?

Comment: That's one way. Now at the end, you showed "if there is a solution, then it has to be 1." But then, checking, 1 is *not* a solution. So there is no solution.

Comment: Oh I got it but is there any other method of finding solution so that we don't have to assume that the expression is correct because here assume that the statement is true but I got no solution at the end

Comment: It's the same thing as that false numberphile proof that $1+2+\ldots=-\frac1{12}$. If it existed, it would be that.

Comment: @AmreshPrasadSinha There are no solutions. You showed that.

Comment: I'd start by showing that $\sqrt{x\sqrt{x\sqrt{\cdots}}}=x$ to begin with. By first giving it a precise meaning: Let $x_0=1$ and $x_{n+1}=\sqrt{x x_n}$ and define $\sqrt{x\sqrt{x\sqrt{\cdots}}}:=\lim x_n$ if the limit exists. Then show that the sequence is monotonic and bounded, hence convergent; and show that in fact the limit is just $x$ for all $x\ge 0$. -- After that, your equation becomes $\ln x=x$ is is much less misterious.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen By the way $x_n=x^{\frac{2^n-1}{2^n}}$ so the convergence and that the limit is $x$ is a one-liner (there is no need to use squaring tricks etc.)

Answer (score 4):

Congratulations! You just proved (by contradiction) that no solution exists. Your proof is valid **under the assumption** that $\ln x = \sqrt{x\sqrt{x\cdots}}$ exists. To formalize this, you need only add at the beginning of your proof: "Assume that some $x$ satisfies..." and proceed from here.

A common mistake, particularly when dealing with infinite sums and infinite products, is to assume that a solution exists when it does not. When we start with the assumption "Suppose a solution exists," then either 1) we find out by contradiction that we were wrong, or 2) we may find out some interesting properties that any solution satisfies which can lead us to a solution.

Answer (score 0):

The expression is equivalent to $\ln x=\sqrt{x\ln x}$ which can only be true if $\ln x\ge 0$ or $x\ge 1$. Now for that set of values of $x$, we can square both sides of the equality to get $x=\ln x$ which is again equivalent to $x=e^x$ for which you can clearly see that no solutions exist.

Comment: Why $\sqrt{x \ln(x)}$ ? Shouldn't it be $\sqrt{x\sqrt{x\dots}}=x$ ?

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch Yes I do ultimately get $\ln x= x$, so they are equivalent.

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch $\ln x=\sqrt{xy}$ where $y=\sqrt{x...}$, so $\ln x=y$.

Comment: I am confused how we obtained $\sqrt{x \ln(x)}$ in the first place (since $\sqrt{x\sqrt{x\dots}}=x$) but I agree @DonThousand

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch I used to expression given for $\ln x$ to replace $\sqrt{x\sqrt{x\ldots \infty}}$ with $\ln x$. $\sqrt{x(\sqrt{x}\sqrt{x}\ldots\infty)}=\sqrt{x\ln x}$.

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch We assumed there is a solution to $\ln x=\sqrt{x\sqrt{x\ldots}}$, so we can replace the inner sqrt with $\ln x$.

Comment: Using color might help, $\color{blue}{\ln(x)}=\color{blue}{\sqrt{x\sqrt{x\sqrt{\cdots}}}}$ and so $\ln(x) = \sqrt{x\color{blue}{\sqrt{x\sqrt{x\sqrt{\cdots}}}}}=\sqrt{x\color{blue}{\ln(x)}}$

Comment: @JMoravitz Thanks I got it now. I was thinking about the other approach that we can directly rewrite the equation as $x=\ln(x)$ since $\sqrt{x\sqrt{x\dots}}=\lim_{n\to\infty} x^{\frac{2^n-1}{2^n}}=x$